Router.beforePopState not call on nextjs 14
I'm using nextjs 14 with Incremental Static Regeneration (ISR)
also Router.beforePopState to check URL before go back to previous page.
I put Router.beforePopState inside componentDidMount() in app.js
Implement 2 page: list page and details page (detail page is ISR)
Open list page, then click any item to open detail page, then click back button on browser
Current: it goback without calling beforePopState function
Expect: should call beforePopState function
Router.beforePopState((event) => { saveBackToPage(event.as) return true })
I tried with

useRouter() from "next/router" as same as document
withRouter() to wrap app.js to use this.props.router
They doesn't work

What I see is the code working when I build the app and run locally
Only doesn't work when deploy to uat/test server.
And when I print console.log in conponentDidMount() of app.js
On localhost, I see it only print log when I load list page, not print when click to open detail page
But on UAT, I see it's also print log when I click to open detail page
That's also another different.
Not sure where the issue is, maybe the server config or something, my UAT is using cloudflare
thank you for all your help.
